# Best way to generate PDFs on the server

Tags: .net, asp.net, pdf, aspose

What is the best way would you say to generate PDFs on the server using . NET?
Someone who has tested using Aspose on the server, if so, how does this work?

Comment: We use TallPdf - http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfkit3-versions.aspx , however there are many ways, honestly you could even automate Word on the Server and save as PDF, although Office Automation has never truly been supported by MSFT.

Comment: If you're talking Aspose I'm guessing you're talking about converting files, not generating them from scratch, right?

Comment: Best? Best for what? Readability? RAD? Performance?

Comment: How would you want to generate the PDFs?  In other words html to pdf, directly create pdf, fill in pdf forms, etc.  Can you give more details on exactly what it is you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have already created a generator for Excel. They will generate from xml.

Comment: Oded: Performance at the server memory usage and so on, and how much opportunity you have to change things so that it looks professional.

Comment: For me, I found the best way was to use Reporting services & access it via a web service, but then I was using databased data.

Comment: I have used Aspose to convert Office document to PDF.  Wored on some  but hung on some with no Exception so could not use it in production.  Creation for XML should be pretty clean but for the money I would look at iText first.

Answer (score 2):

iTextSharp is a good free solution (I have successfully used it).  Check out:

- http://somewebguy.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/itextsharp-simplify-your-html-to-pdf-creation/
  (Great library to use if you make iTextSharp your formal solution)
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ITextSharpHelperClass.aspx

There are a bunch of paid solutions (Aspose being one of them) out there but haven't had the need to try them yet.

I do not recommend using the JET driver or any type of MS office automation.  It is not supported and rarely works consistently.

Comment: Please note that latest versions of iTextSharp (and iText) are also a "paid solution" unless you open source code of your application.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open source option: http://itextpdf.com/ (ITextSharp)

Comment: Would you say that this is good enough for enterprise applications? Solutions to replace its dhtmlX php solution to export grids from JavaScript to XML that is sent to the server where generated with color, grouping, sorting and so on to a PDF.

Comment: @sv88erfik, yes ti could be used ( and it is ) in enterprise applicastions. Have a look at the licensing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try syncfusion. It is a very good component with excellent support.

http://asp.syncfusion.com/sfaspnetsamplebrowser/9.1.0.20/Web/Pdf.Web/samples/4.0/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Developer Evangelist at Aspose. And I would like to share with you that you may use [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) to create PDF files from scratch. You can use this component on Server and the Client alike. You can also use it on various servers and on 32-bit or 64-bit systems seamlessly.

The samples, tutorials and support are also available. You can also use the [trial version](http://www.aspose.com/community/files/51/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/category1184.aspx) at your end for testing purposes before you buy it.

If you have any related questions, please do let me know, so I could guide you accordingly.